# Drop Shadow with Golang based on alpha

Tags: image, go, shadow

I need to drop shadow from an object of type `image.Image` which has got an alpha channel. The goal is not to have the rectangle shadowed, but the alpha.

What I wanted to do is:

- take out the alpha channel
- turn it into a black RGB image
- expand to N pixels (N=the size of the blur)
- apply a gaussian blur
- apply it as a background

The last point is quite simple, thanks to the "image/draw" API (I have no problem to cut an image in circle, and apply the mask, for example).

Outputting the alpha channel seems simple, too (for each pixel, apply a 255*alpha multiplication on R, G, and B, or use a grayscale image, and finally invert the white color to black)

It's clearly the dilation and blurring that I have a problem with.

I have nothing against the fact that the image changes size for this operation (at worst I will reduce the original image before transformation)

The question is "how to dilate and blur the alpha channel" with Go on an `image.Image`?

Comment: I think it may help to cut down / refocus your question to what specific point(s) you need to solve.  Currently most of your question is explaining details that you *don't* need help with, while the parts that you *do* need help with, aren't that clear yet (at least to me). For example, I'm not sure you what you specifically mean by "expand to N pixels" and "dilation".

Comment: @HymnsForDisco N is the size of the shadow, because the alpha channel will stick to the mask, so the alpha need to be dilated I guess. I edited my question. The only thing that is needed is to have a track to dilate and blur an alpha channel with `image.Image`

Answer (score 2):

OK, after a while, I finally made this.

I rebuild the alpha and devide it by 2 (this will be a paramters).

I'm using `github.com/disintegration/imaging` package to blur the alpha.

```golang
func DropShadow(img image.Image, size float64) image.Image {
    bounds := img.Bounds()
    sizeInt := int(math.Ceil(size)) * 4
    final := imaging.New(bounds.Dx()+sizeInt, bounds.Dy()+sizeInt, color.Alpha{})

    for x := 0; x < bounds.Dx(); x++ {
        for y := 0; y < bounds.Dy(); y++ {
            _, _, _, a := img.At(x, y).RGBA()
            final.Set(x+sizeInt/2, y+sizeInt/2, color.RGBA{0x0, 0x0, 0x0, uint8(a / 2)})
        }
    }
    final = imaging.Blur(final, size)
    final = imaging.Overlay(final, img, image.Point{sizeInt / 2, sizeInt / 2}, 1)

    return final
}
```

It's only a bit curious that I need to scale by 4 the image to not have the shadow sticking to the border. But it does the job...